# Is there any event to toggle the color of element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `button` which hide/shows a `div`. I have used `.toggle()` to hide and show that element. Now I need to also change the color of that button too. I mean when element shows, the color of button has to be *red*, else it has to be *gray*.

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $("div").toggle();
});
```

```css
button{
  background-color: red;
}

div{
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click!</button> <br /><br />
<div>this is a test</div>
```

As you see in the above code, background-color of `button` is *red* because `div` is visible. Now I want to change background-color of `button` to *gray* when user clicks on it and `div` hides. How can I do that?

I can do that using something like this:

```
if( $(div).is(":visible") ){
     // background color of button: red
} else {
    // background color of button: gray
}
```

But I want to know, is there any event to toggle the color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the `background-color` to `gray` if it's `red` and vice versa.

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
  $(this).css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)' ? 'rgb(128,128,128)' : 'rgb(255,0,0)')
  $("div").toggle();
});
```

```css
button{
  background-color: red;
}

div{
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click!</button> <br /><br />
<div>this is a test</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the colour of the button to a style class and use .toggleClass(classname)

Comment: You can also use .addClass() and .removeClass() if you need more control over it

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific event to toggle color.  You can use any (maybe?) event to toggle color.  There are at least a couple of ways to toggle color.

You can use your code to toggle the color in the click event handler of the button.

```
$(document).on('click', '#id_of_button', function(){
    if( $('#id_of_div').is(':visible') ){
         // background color of button: red
    } else {
        // background color of button: gray
    }
})
```

However, I would define a css class for the background colors instead of manipulating the style directly.

As mentioned by Santhosh - you can use define a class and use `toggleClass`.

As mentioned by chipChocolate.py - you can use a ternary expression to swap the colors.

You can use the code you in your post to handle it.

So, in the end...

There is no `toggleColor` event or function, but you could write one, or use some other event to accomplish the task.

Comment: I literally mention in the question I want to know another approach ..!

Comment: "But I want to know, is there any event to toggle the color?" Your question is specifically answered.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $("div").toggle(function(){
      if($(this).is(":visible"))
        $("button").css("background-color","silver");
      else
        $("button").css("background-color","red");
    });
});
```

```css
button{
  background-color: red;
}

div{
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click!</button> <br /><br />
<div>this is a test</div>
```

Comment: I literally mention in the question I want to know another approach ..!

Answer (score 1):

**Try the below code:**

```js
$("button").click(function(e) {
    $(".container").toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.container div{
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid;
  padding: 20px;
}
.container div
{
  display: none;
}
button{
  background-color: gray;
}
.active button{
  background-color: red;
}
.active div
{
display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <button>click!</button> <br /><br />
  <div>this is a test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't have other events. All you need to know is HTML5 events.

You can a class on button to track changes.

Comment: HTML5 events? I didn't get it .!